# Add default Item to data bound ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I have a function that brings back a datatable **[GetDrinks()]**

I use the function to populate a data source.

I want add a default value '*Select Drink*' but it doesn't seem to work as it only shows the values form the datagrid.

Any ideas to get around this?

```
cboDrinks.DataSource = GetDrinks()
cboDrinks.DisplayMember = "Drink_DESCN"
cboDrinks.ValueMember = "Drink_ID"

cboDrinks.Items.Insert(0, " Select Drink ")
cboDrinks.SelectedIndex = 0
```

Comment: Insert it into the DataTable you get from GetDrinks().

Comment: Sorry I can't do that as it also being use elsewhere in the program.

Comment: No it's not.  GetDrinks returns a *copy* of a DataTable, does it not?  You insert your row into the *copy* you are receiving.

Comment: I totally get what you are saying now. I will give that a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comment, you need to insert the data into the DataTable that you are getting from GetDrinks:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = GetDrinks()
Dim row as DataRow = dt.NewRow
row("Drink_ID") = 0
row("Drink_DESCN") = " Select Drink "
dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0)

cboDrinks.DisplayMember = "Drink_DESCN"
cboDrinks.ValueMember = "Drink_ID"
cboDrinks.DataSource = dt
cboDrinks.SelectedIndex = 0
```

Note: Set the DisplayMember and ValueMember before the DataSource to avoid multiple refresh calls to the control.